# Why it's throwing error while setting up Eureka configuration in application.yml?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, microservices, netflix-eureka

I am new to microservices where I have to use two services (which I have made in separate projects). And now I am trying to set up Eureka configuration in my `application.yml` file [image: like]:

But it's throwing errors as can be seen in the screenshot above:

```
Nested mappings are not allowed in compact mapping
```

and

```
Multiple markers at this line:
- Nested mappings are not allowed in compact mapping
- Implicit keys need to be on a single line
```

Additionally, I tried with

I am sharing my `EServerApplication.java` code below:

```
package com.eserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and below is my `pom.xml` file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.eserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>e_server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>e_server</name>
    <description>This is a microservice for eureka server</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

But, when I do configure the same thing in `application.properties` file, it works well. [image]

and below is the console output:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.3)

2022-01-27 14:52:11.965  INFO 14444 --- [           main] com.eserver.EServerApplication           : Starting EServerApplication using Java 17.0.1 on SHAHFAISALKHAN with PID 14444 (C:\Users\shahf\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.13.0.RELEASE\e_server\target\classes started by shahf in C:\Users\shahf\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.13.0.RELEASE\e_server)
2022-01-27 14:52:11.970  INFO 14444 --- [           main] com.eserver.EServerApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-01-27 14:52:13.550  INFO 14444 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=0f4543fa-8866-3a60-8d6e-f4ead7a36662
2022-01-27 14:52:13.981  INFO 14444 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8761 (http)
2022-01-27 14:52:13.993  INFO 14444 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-01-27 14:52:13.993  INFO 14444 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
2022-01-27 14:52:14.275  INFO 14444 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-01-27 14:52:14.275  INFO 14444 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2203 ms
2022-01-27 14:52:15.013  INFO 14444 --- [           main] c.s.j.s.i.a.WebApplicationImpl           : Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.4 05/24/2017 03:20 PM'
2022-01-27 14:52:15.089  INFO 14444 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2022-01-27 14:52:15.091  INFO 14444 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2022-01-27 14:52:15.299  INFO 14444 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2022-01-27 14:52:15.300  INFO 14444 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2022-01-27 14:52:19.162  INFO 14444 --- [           main] DiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration : Eureka HTTP Client uses Jersey
2022-01-27 14:52:19.326  WARN 14444 --- [           main] iguration$LoadBalancerCaffeineWarnLogger : Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is currently working with the default cache. You can switch to using Caffeine cache, by adding it and org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager to the classpath.
2022-01-27 14:52:19.393  INFO 14444 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2022-01-27 14:52:19.494  INFO 14444 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2022-01-27 14:52:19.495  INFO 14444 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Client configured to neither register nor query for data.
2022-01-27 14:52:19.525  INFO 14444 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1643275339522 with initial instances count: 0
2022-01-27 14:52:19.657  INFO 14444 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initializing ...
2022-01-27 14:52:19.665  INFO 14444 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Adding new peer nodes [http://localhost:8761/eureka/]
2022-01-27 14:52:20.036  INFO 14444 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2022-01-27 14:52:20.036  INFO 14444 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2022-01-27 14:52:20.036  INFO 14444 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2022-01-27 14:52:20.036  INFO 14444 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2022-01-27 14:52:20.177  INFO 14444 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-01-27 14:52:20.178  INFO 14444 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-01-27 14:52:20.333  INFO 14444 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Replica node URL:  http://localhost:8761/eureka/
2022-01-27 14:52:20.377  INFO 14444 --- [           main] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Finished initializing remote region registries. All known remote regions: []
2022-01-27 14:52:20.386  INFO 14444 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initialized
2022-01-27 14:52:20.396  INFO 14444 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2022-01-27 14:52:20.408  INFO 14444 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 230 ms
2022-01-27 14:52:20.547  INFO 14444 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application UNKNOWN with eureka with status UP
2022-01-27 14:52:20.551  INFO 14444 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Setting the eureka configuration..
2022-01-27 14:52:20.567  INFO 14444 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : isAws returned false
2022-01-27 14:52:20.568  INFO 14444 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Initialized server context
2022-01-27 14:52:20.568  INFO 14444 --- [       Thread-9] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Got 1 instances from neighboring DS node
2022-01-27 14:52:20.569  INFO 14444 --- [       Thread-9] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Renew threshold is: 1
2022-01-27 14:52:20.570  INFO 14444 --- [       Thread-9] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Changing status to UP
2022-01-27 14:52:20.606  INFO 14444 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8761 (http) with context path ''
2022-01-27 14:52:20.607  INFO 14444 --- [           main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8761
2022-01-27 14:52:20.692  INFO 14444 --- [       Thread-9] e.s.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration : Started Eureka Server
2022-01-27 14:52:21.438  INFO 14444 --- [           main] com.eserver.EServerApplication           : Started EServerApplication in 11.215 seconds (JVM running for 12.441)
2022-01-27 14:53:20.580  INFO 14444 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2022-01-27 14:54:20.579  INFO 14444 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
```

Please guide me how can I can I fix the `application.yml` error.

**EDIT: [SOLVED]**

I found that this yml configuration file is sensitive to white-space of each components and hence I corrected it in my program. Closing the thread now!

Comment: sorry, (tried, ) cannot reproduce! ([starter](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.6.3&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=eureka-server-demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=cloud-eureka-server), runs with .properties as .yml (as .yaml))

Comment: I am also looking for answers but no success till now. I tried to download and import the project from spring initializr but still, it gives such yml issue. Gonna uninstall STS and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

yaml files follow a different naming convention. The following properties should resolve your issue.

```
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
  server:
    wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty: 0
```